# NoReverseMatch at /posts/ Error in Django project

Tags: python, django

I write simple Django-blog, *django.VERSION - (2, 0, 1, 'final', 0)*
But I receive an error and don't understand how to fix it.

```
NoReverseMatch at /posts/
Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'id': 16}' not found. 1 
pattern(s) tried: ['posts\\/(?P<id>\\d)/$']
```

And

```
Error during template rendering
In template 

djangoblog/posts/templates/posts/base.html, error at line 0

Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'id': 16}' not found. 1 
pattern(s) tried: ['posts\\/(?P<id>\\d)/$']
1   {% load staticfiles %}
2   <!DOCTYPE html>
3   <html lang="en">
4   <head>
5       <meta charset="UTF-8">
6       <title>{% block head_title %}
7           Django-blog! {% endblock head_title %}</title>
8       <link rel="stylesheet"
9
```

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, 
auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp', '-updated']
```

My def in views.py look like

```
def post_list(request):
    queryset_list = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 5)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    queryset = paginator.get_page(page)
    context = {
        'object_list': queryset,
        'title': 'List'
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/post_list.html', context)
```

in urls.py urlpatterns look like

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^$', post_list, name='list'),
    re_path('^create/$', post_create),
    re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d)/delete/$', post_delete),
]
```

Thank you very much.
If you need another information - tell me, please.

Comment: Where are the rest of the URLs? In particular the detail one, which is clearly the one with the problem.

Comment: add url like `path('posts/<int:section>/', views.detail, name='detail')`

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: It's work, thank you, @ Anjaneyulu Batta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is looking for a url named `'detail'` which you have not yet created and therefore throws an error.

you need to create a view like `post_detail` and include this in a url with name `detail`, e.g.

```
re_path('posts/(?P<id>\d+)/$', post_detail, name='detail')
```